# Behaviour of the align environment

Tags: math-mode, packages, amsmath, align

I'm writing a manuscript with long equations. In order to break the equations I prefer the `align` environment, provided by the `amsmath` package, over the `eqnarray` one.

In the below example I show the kind of align I need. The `eqnarray` gives the correct behaviour, will the `align` one drops a space after the `&` symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
  \vec{F} &=& m\vec{a}\\
          && + \frac{dm}{dt} \vec{v}
\end{eqnarray}  

\begin{align}
  \vec{F} =& m\vec{a}\\
          & + \frac{dm}{dt} \vec{v}
\end{align}  

\end{document}
```

**Question**

Is it possible to replicate the first example using `align`?

Comment: please note -- the answer, to put `=` *after the `&`, is stated clearly in the documentation: `texdoc amsmath`, near the top of p.3.  (but, of course, nobody ever reads documentation ...)

Comment: Why `eqnarray` shouldn't be used: [Avoid `eqnarray`](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: @Barbara: has it ever been explained why one need the `{}` pair then one use `={}&` ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've read it, however the = after the & gives a result I'm not looking for.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Wonderful link, Thx.

Comment: @daleif -- the `{}` pair is needed to indicate that there's an actual "something" next to the `=`; i'm not sure it has been explained anywhere, but it's basic to tex itself. as an exercise, enter the code for the first multi-line display on p.192 of the texbook as (plain) `\eqalign` with `&=` and then again with `=&` as the only differences in the two examples. run it through (plain) tex and look at the output. the "null" condition isn't in the spacing table on p.170, but the result is clear.  `amsmath` simply followed this model, depending on the default outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for *align* to generate a similar result to *eqnarray* as in the example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
  \vec{F} &=& m\vec{a}\\
          && + \frac{dm}{dt} \vec{v}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

a pair of curly brackets should be used between the = sign and the &, as below,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \vec{F} ={}& m\vec{a}\\
          & + \frac{dm}{dt} \vec{v}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

**Acknowledgements**

I'd like to thank to **daleif** and **TorbjørnT** for pointing out the answer, and for recommending the [manuscript](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) by *Lars Madsen*,

> Avoid eqnarray!

*The Practex Journal, 2006, No. 4*

Answer (score 7):

You should put `=` after `&`. I have added `\phantom{=:} to push the`+`to right. (IMO it would be nice if we put this`+` at the end of first line.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
  \vec{F} &=& m\vec{a}\\
          && + \frac{dm}{dt} \vec{v}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{align}
  \vec{F} &= m\vec{a} \\
          & \phantom{=:} + \frac{dm}{dt} \vec{v}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** As per the suggestion of @egreg (who is a mathematician hence I don't say no to what he says :) ) instead of `\phantom{=:}` one can use `\qquad` to push things to right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
  \vec{F} &=& m\vec{a}\\
          && + \frac{dm}{dt} \vec{v}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{align}
  \vec{F} &= m\vec{a} \\
         & \qquad + \frac{dm}{dt} \vec{v}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: It is advisable **NOT to use** eqnarray.

Comment: I'd use `\qquad` instead of `\phantom`

Comment: @egreg: As you wish. I added it in the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I usually use `= {} &` and just `&+` instead. You might also find the `\MoveEqLeft` macro from `mathtools` useful. Instead of starting a line with `&...` and indenting the other lines, starting a line with `\MoveEqLeft ...` move this line backwards (2ems). This makes it easy to to the equation setup recommended in *Mathematics into Type* (or see the drawings in my (danish) LaTeX book, chapter 4)

Comment: @daleif Thank you! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

okay, this "answer" stretches the bounds of what is proper here, but continued recommendations to place the `&` in an `amsmath` alignment *after* the sign of relation are simply wrong.

the proper placement of the `&` is *before* the sign of relation. this is basic to tex itself.

as an exercise, here is the code for the first multi-line display on p.192 of the texbook as (plain) `\eqalign` with `&=` and then again with `=&` as the only differences in the two examples.

```
$$\eqalign{%
  (x+y)(x-y) &= x^2 -xy +yx -y^2\cr
             &= x^2 -y^2\cr
  (x+y)^2    &= x^2 +2xy +y^2\cr
}$$
%
now, with ampersands and equal signs interchanged:
%
$$\eqalign{%
  (x+y)(x-y) =& x^2 -xy +yx -y^2\cr
             =& x^2 -y^2\cr
  (x+y)^2    =& x^2 +2xy +y^2\cr
}$$

\bye
```

here is the output:

[image]

the spacing is governed by the values in the spacing table on p.170.
the "null" condition represented by the `=` sign followed by `&` isn't in that table.
however, the result is clear. amsmath simply followed this model, and depends on the default outcome.